# How do you use script variables in psql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, variables, psql

In MS SQL Server, I create my scripts to use customizable variables:

```
DECLARE @somevariable int  
SELECT @somevariable = -1

INSERT INTO foo VALUES ( @somevariable )
```

I'll then change the value of `@somevariable` at runtime, depending on the value that I want in the particular situation. Since it's at the top of the script it's easy to see and remember.

How do I do the same with the PostgreSQL client `psql`?

Comment: FWIW, the \set operator _appears_ to be related to the psql command-line tool, not to the pgsql batch language. I could be wrong.

Comment: What version of Postgres are you on?

Answer (score 242, accepted):

Postgres variables are created through the \set command, for example ...

```
\set myvariable value
```

... and can then be substituted, for example, as ...

```
SELECT * FROM :myvariable.table1;
```

... or ...

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE :myvariable IS NULL;
```

*edit: As of psql 9.1, variables can be expanded in quotes as in:*

```
\set myvariable value 

SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1 = :'myvariable';
```

*In older versions of the psql client:*

... If you want to use the variable as the value in a conditional string query, such as ...

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1 = ':myvariable';
```

... then you need to include the quotes in the variable itself as the above will not work.  Instead define your variable as such ...

```
\set myvariable 'value'
```

However, if, like me, you ran into a situation in which you wanted to make a string from an existing variable, I found the trick to be this ...

```
\set quoted_myvariable '\'' :myvariable '\''
```

Now you have both a quoted and unquoted variable of the same string!  And you can do something like this ....

```
INSERT INTO :myvariable.table1 SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE column1 = :quoted_myvariable;
```

Comment: `\set` is only for `psql` tool, you cannot use it in stored procedures!

Comment: @SorinSbarnea the OP asked about *script*, not *procedure*

Comment: This answer mixes `psql` meta-commands `\set` with PostgreSQL commands in a confusing fashion.

Comment: As of postgresql 9.1, in psql you can now use :'variable' to have it properly quoted as a value for you, or :"variable" to use it as an identifier.

Comment: The second one `\set quoted_myvariable '\'' :myvariable '\''` gives you the quotes in the variable.

Comment: \set works like a C macro. You can't use it to store the result of a function, like RANDOM() or NOW().

Comment: `\set myvar 'value'` does not work the way you describe. You have to use `\set myvar '\'value\''`

Comment: instead of quoting, you can use a cast too: \set myvariable abcd, then select col from table where attr = :myvariable::varchar, for instance

Comment: @laurent: Or use `:'myvar'` like @HitScan suggests

Comment: It is a bad practice to provide non working code: ':myvariable'.
I see code and don't read comments that it is wrong code. So lost some time to detect bug and revoke my script from collegues.
A way better is just provide correct code.

Comment: quoting with `$$` also works - `\set quoted_myvariable $$':myvariable'$$`

Comment: also variant with arrays: 1. `\set args $$'{"text", "text", "text", "text"}'$$::text[]` is same as `\set args ARRAY[$$'text'$$, $$'text'$$, $$'text'$$, $$'text'$$]`

Answer (score 76):

One final word on PSQL variables:

1. They don't expand if you enclose them in single quotes in the SQL statement. 
   Thus this doesn't work:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = ':myvariable'
   ```
2. To expand to a string literal in a SQL statement, you have to include the quotes in the variable set. However, the variable value already has to be enclosed in quotes, which means that you need a *second* set of quotes, and the inner set has to be escaped. Thus you need:

   ```
   \set myvariable '\'somestring\''  
   SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = :myvariable
   ```

   **EDIT**: starting with PostgreSQL 9.1, you may write instead:

   ```
   \set myvariable somestring
   SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = :'myvariable'
   ```

Answer (score 71):

You can try to use a [WITH](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/queries-with.html) clause.

```
WITH vars AS (SELECT 42 AS answer, 3.14 AS appr_pi)
SELECT t.*, vars.answer, t.radius*vars.appr_pi
FROM table AS t, vars;
```

Comment: This way is mostly convenient when you are using same computed values few times in your query.

Comment: Contrary to Bryce's report, it seems to work fine for me.

    `CREATE TABLE test (name VARCHAR, age INT);`

    `INSERT INTO test (name, age) VALUES ('Jack', 21), ('Jill', 20);`

    `WITH vars AS (SELECT N'Jack' AS name, 21 AS age)
    SELECT test.* FROM test, vars
    WHERE test.name = vars.name and test.age = vars.age;`


Ouputs Jack and Jack's age, as expected.

Comment: For a lot of uses, especially within the context of a web application framework like Python Flask, this is the best solution for reusing complex calculated values within a single query.

Comment: Can anyone suggest how this might work in an insert?

Comment: @Stoopkid `create table t(x integer);`

`insert into t(x) 
with sub as (select 999 as num)
select num from sub;`

`select * from t;`

Comment: with vars as (select 42 as uid) select id from users where id = vars.uid  returns error: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "vars"

Comment: @Artem try adding vars to the FROM clause: `... from users, vars where ...`

Answer (score 49):

Specifically for `psql`, you can pass `psql` variables from the command line too; you can pass them with `-v`. Here's a usage example:

```
$ psql -v filepath=/path/to/my/directory/mydatafile.data regress
regress=> SELECT :'filepath';
               ?column?                
---------------------------------------
 /path/to/my/directory/mydatafile.data
(1 row)
```

Note that the colon is unquoted, then the variable name its self is quoted. Odd syntax, I know. This only works in psql but doesn't work with `-c` / `--command`; you have to send the command via stdin or via `-f`. It won't work in (say) PgAdmin-III too.

This substitution happens during input processing in psql, so you can't (say) define a function that uses `:'filepath'` and expect the value of `:'filepath'` to change from session to session. It'll be substituted once, when the function is defined, and then will be a constant after that. It's useful for scripting but not runtime use.

Comment: psql variables, e.g. :'filepath', you pointed out: "Note that the colon is unquoted, then the variable name its self is quoted." Thank! You! I already put a bunch of forehead-shaped dents into my desk trying to make this work, and you just saved me a ton more. Exactly what I needed for some scripting.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with `--command="SELECT :'filepath';"`, which is unfortunate. How can this be useful if it seems to require interactive terminal sessions?

Comment: However `echo "\set filepath /path/to/my/directory/mydatafile.data \\\\\\\\ SELECT :'filepath';" | psql` does work. Note the excessive number of escaping slashes to achieve two sequential \ characters, as per the advice under the `command` arg [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html), with a Bash shell anyway.

Comment: @alphabetasoup Yep, you can use `psql -f -` etc. Like many things, `psql` isn't exactly pretty, but it gets the job done. It's easier to use `-v` than to compose a `\set` command in stdin though.

Comment: Variable expansion does not appear to be supported inside a `\COPY` command as of PSQL 15. `\COPY (SELECT * FROM mydata WHERE item_id = :'item_id') TO './myfile.tsv'` results in a syntax error at `:'item_id'`.

Comment: @shadowtalker Very likely, there are all sorts of weird limitations in it. For exmple psql's conditionals cannot be used to guard the COPY data stream because the parser for `\endif` is confused by the `\.` to end the copy-stream...

Answer (score 15):

FWIW, the real problem was that I had included a semicolon at the end of my \set command:

> \set owner_password 'thepassword';

The semicolon was interpreted as an actual character in the variable:

> \echo :owner_password
>   thepassword;

So when I tried to use it:

> CREATE ROLE myrole LOGIN UNENCRYPTED PASSWORD :owner_password NOINHERIT CREATEDB CREATEROLE VALID UNTIL 'infinity';

...I got this:

> CREATE ROLE myrole LOGIN UNENCRYPTED PASSWORD thepassword; NOINHERIT CREATEDB CREATEROLE VALID UNTIL 'infinity';

That not only failed to set the quotes around the literal, but split the command into 2 parts (the second of which was invalid as it started with "NOINHERIT").

The moral of this story: PostgreSQL "variables" are really macros used in text expansion, not true values. I'm sure that comes in handy, but it's tricky at first.

Answer (score 13):

postgres (since version 9.0) allows anonymous blocks in any of the supported server-side scripting languages

```
DO '
DECLARE somevariable int = -1;
BEGIN
INSERT INTO foo VALUES ( somevariable );
END
' ;
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html

As everything is inside a string, external string variables being substituted in will need to be escaped and quoted twice.  Using dollar quoting instead will not give full protection against SQL injection.

Answer (score 11):

You need to use one of the procedural languages such as PL/pgSQL not the SQL proc language.
In PL/pgSQL you can use vars right in SQL statements.
For single quotes you can use the quote literal function.

Comment: It cannot be done in postgres itself, but it can be done in the PSQL client application.

Comment: plpgsql can (now) be used in  postgres (since version 9.0) )http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-do.html

Answer (score 9):

I solved it with a temp table.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_session_variables (
    "sessionSalt" TEXT
);
INSERT INTO temp_session_variables ("sessionSalt") VALUES (current_timestamp || RANDOM()::TEXT);
```

This way, I had a "variable" I could use over multiple queries, that is unique for the session. I needed it to generate unique "usernames" while still not having collisions if importing users with the same user name.

Comment: This seem to be the only working way in visual tools like Heidi SQL.

Answer (score 5):

Another approach is to (ab)use the PostgreSQL GUC mechanism to create variables. See [this prior answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13172964/398670) for details and examples.

You declare the GUC in `postgresql.conf`, then change its value at runtime with `SET` commands and get its value with `current_setting(...)`.

I don't recommend this for general use, but it could be useful in narrow cases like the one mentioned in the linked question, where the poster wanted a way to provide the application-level username to triggers and functions.

Answer (score 5):

I really miss that feature. Only way to achieve something similar is to use functions.

I have used it in two ways:

- perl functions that use $_SHARED variable
- store your variables in table

Perl version:

```
   CREATE FUNCTION var(name text, val text) RETURNS void AS $$
        $_SHARED{$_[0]} = $_[1];
   $$ LANGUAGE plperl;
   CREATE FUNCTION var(name text) RETURNS text AS $$
        return $_SHARED{$_[0]};
   $$ LANGUAGE plperl;
```

Table version:

```
CREATE TABLE var (
  sess bigint NOT NULL,
  key varchar NOT NULL,
  val varchar,
  CONSTRAINT var_pkey PRIMARY KEY (sess, key)
);
CREATE FUNCTION var(key varchar, val anyelement) RETURNS void AS $$
  DELETE FROM var WHERE sess = pg_backend_pid() AND key = $1;
  INSERT INTO var (sess, key, val) VALUES (sessid(), $1, $2::varchar);
$$ LANGUAGE 'sql';

CREATE FUNCTION var(varname varchar) RETURNS varchar AS $$
  SELECT val FROM var WHERE sess = pg_backend_pid() AND key = $1;
$$ LANGUAGE 'sql';
```

Notes:

- plperlu is faster than perl
- pg_backend_pid is not best session identification, consider using pid combined with backend_start from pg_stat_activity
- this table version is also bad because you have to clear this is up occasionally (and not delete currently working session variables)

Answer (score 4):

Variables in `psql` suck. If you want to declare an integer, you have to enter the integer, then do a carriage return, then end the statement in a semicolon. Observe:

Let's say I want to declare an integer variable `my_var` and insert it into a table `test`:

Example table `test`:

```
thedatabase=# \d test;
                         Table "public.test"
 Column |  Type   |                     Modifiers                     
--------+---------+---------------------------------------------------
 id     | integer | not null default nextval('test_id_seq'::regclass)
Indexes:
    "test_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

Clearly, nothing in this table yet:

```
thedatabase=# select * from test;
 id 
----
(0 rows)
```

We declare a variable. **Notice how the semicolon is on the next line!**

```
thedatabase=# \set my_var 999
thedatabase=# ;
```

Now we can insert. We have to use this weird "`:''`" looking syntax:

```
thedatabase=# insert into test(id) values (:'my_var');
INSERT 0 1
```

It worked!

```
thedatabase=# select * from test;
 id  
-----
 999
(1 row)
```

**Explanation:**

So... what happens if we don't have the semicolon on the next line? The variable? Have a look:

We declare `my_var` without the new line.

```
thedatabase=# \set my_var 999;
```

Let's select `my_var`.

```
thedatabase=# select :'my_var';
 ?column? 
----------
 999;
(1 row)
```

WTF is that? It's not an *integer*, it's a **string** `999;`!

```
thedatabase=# select 999;
 ?column? 
----------
      999
(1 row)
```

Comment: The reason the semicolon does unexpected things for you is that a semicolon terminates a SQL statement, but you're typing a psql command, \set, which isn't SQL and does NOT take a terminating semicolon.
Putting a semicolon on the next line won't hurt, but does absolutely nothing. It's an empty statement.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use the `:'my_var'` syntax for an integer value. `:my_var` works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

I've found this question and the answers extremely useful, but also confusing.  I had lots of trouble getting quoted variables to work, so here is the way I got it working:

```
\set deployment_user username    -- username
\set deployment_pass '\'string_password\''
ALTER USER :deployment_user WITH PASSWORD :deployment_pass;
```

This way you can define the variable in one statement.  When you use it, single quotes will be embedded into the variable.

NOTE!  When I put a comment after the quoted variable it got sucked in as part of the variable when I tried some of the methods in other answers.  That was really screwing me up for a while.  With this method comments appear to be treated as you'd expect.

Comment: `\set deployment_pass 'string_password'`
`ALTER USER :deployment_user WITH PASSWORD :'deployment_pass';`

Comment: \set is not SQL it's a psql built-in command sql comments are not supported.

Answer (score 2):

I've posted a new solution for this [on another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316773/is-there-a-way-to-define-a-named-constant-in-a-postgresql-query/54322738#54322738).

It uses a table to store variables, and can be updated at any time. A static immutable getter function is dynamically created (by another function), triggered by update to your table.  You get nice table storage, plus the blazing fast speeds of an immutable getter.