# Declare local variables in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, local-variables, declare

There is an almost identical, but not really answered question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490942/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-a-postgresql-query).

I am migrating an application from MS SQL Server to PostgreSQL. In many places in code I use local variables so I would like to go for the change that requires less work, so could you please tell me which is the best way to translate the following code?

```
-- MS SQL Syntax: declare 2 variables, assign value and return the sum of the two 
declare @One integer = 1
declare @Two integer = 2
select @One + @Two as SUM
```

this returns:

```
SUM
-----------
3

(1 row(s) affected)
```

I will use Postgresql 8.4 or even 9.0 if it contains significant fetaures that will simplify the translation.

Comment: this post might help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36959/how-do-you-use-script-variables-in-postgresql

Comment: Possible identical to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36959/how-do-you-use-script-variables-in-postgresql

Comment: Seems like you have to wait for 9.0 - ["DO -- execute an anonymous code block"](http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/sql-do.html).

Comment: @jeppinstall: yes they say You need to use one of the procedural languages such as PL/pgSQL not the SQL proc language... So which is the PL/pgSQL syntax for that?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Postgresql historically doesn't support procedural code at the command level - only within functions. However, in Postgresql 9, support has been added to [execute an inline code block](http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/sql-do.html) that effectively supports something like this, although the syntax is perhaps a bit odd, and there are many restrictions compared to what you can do with SQL Server. Notably, the inline code block can't return a result set, so can't be used for what you outline above.

In general, if you want to write some procedural code and have it return a result, you need to put it inside a function. For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION somefuncname() RETURNS int LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE
  one int;
  two int;
BEGIN
  one := 1;
  two := 2;
  RETURN one + two;
END
$$;
SELECT somefuncname();
```

The PostgreSQL wire protocol doesn't, as far as I know, allow for things like a command returning multiple result sets. So you can't simply map T-SQL batches or stored procedures to PostgreSQL functions.

Comment: the wire protocol allows several commands. and thus several different result sets (in asynchronous mode).

Comment: @Jasen I specifically meant a single query returning multiple result sets/result counts, rather than having several query-response cycles in flight. Although even that situation may have changed since 2010.

Comment: it may be possible to re-write the task as several calls. `select * from f1(); select * from f2(); select * from f3();` and so receive several different result sets.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare local variables with `:=`, `=` in `DECLARE` clause as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func()
RETURNS INT
AS $$
DECLARE
  value1 INT := 1; -- Here
  value2 INT = 2; -- Here
  value3 INT DEFAULT 3; -- Here
  value4 CONSTANT INT := 4; -- Here
  value5 INT; -- Here
BEGIN
  RETURN value1 + value2 + value3;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

*Memos:

- `:=`, `=` and `DEFAULT` are the same.
- Trying to change the constant local variable `value4` gets error.
- The uninitialized local variable `value5` is `NULL`.
- You can declare local variables with `DECLARE` clause in a PL/pgSQL function and procedure and `DO` statement.

Then, calling `my_func()` returns `6` as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func();
 my_func
---------
       6
(1 row)
```