# Can't declare variable inside function on PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, local-variables

I am writing function in PostgreSQL but it doesn't allow me to declare variable inside it. Here is the function.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION clean_emp() RETURNS void AS 
$func$
DECLARE cnt varchar;
      
$func$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Error Message

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "varchar"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 66
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not surprise. The language SQL doesn't support variables. You have to use the language plpgsql.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION clean_emp()
RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE cnt varchar;
BEGIN
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

See more in documentation http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html.

PostgreSQL has more languages for writing function. The SQL language is perfect for one line single statement macros. The PLpgSQL is classical native language similar to Oracle's PL/SQL with embedded SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare local variables with `:=`, `=` in [DECLARE clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html) as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157753/declare-local-variables-in-postgresql/77633234#77633234) explains how to declare local variables in detail:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
DECLARE
  value1 INTEGER := 1; -- Here
  value2 INTEGER = 2; -- Here
  value3 INTEGER DEFAULT 3; -- Here
BEGIN
RETURN value1 + value2 + value3;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```