# PostgreSQL reusing value from long calculation in CASE statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I have the following:

```
SELECT
 CASE column1
  WHEN some_long_calc THEN 10
  ELSE some_long_calc + 2*PI
  END AS mycalc,
```

How can I "save" `some_long_calc` as a local variable so I don't need to run it twice?

I am using `atan2` and I want to keep my angle range between 0 and 2pi

Comment: waht does AS INT do ?

Comment: @Eric - PostgreSQL does not have declared variables.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157753/how-to-declare-local-variables-in-postgresql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I guess that query optimizer is smart enough to spot the same deterministic expressions and do not calculate it twice.

If this is not applicable you could use [`LATERAL`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL):

```
SELECT *,
  CASE column1
     WHEN sub.long_calc THEN 10
     ELSE sub.long_calc + 2 * 3.14
  END AS mycalc
FROM tab t
,LATERAL (VALUES(t.a+t.b+t.c)) AS sub(long_calc);
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8b7e4/1/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════╦══════════╦════╦════╦════╦════════════╦════════╗
║ id  ║ column1  ║ a  ║ b  ║ c  ║ long_calc  ║ mycalc ║
╠═════╬══════════╬════╬════╬════╬════════════╬════════╣
║  1  ║       6  ║ 1  ║ 2  ║ 3  ║         6  ║ 10     ║
║  2  ║      20  ║ 2  ║ 3  ║ 4  ║         9  ║ 15.28  ║
╚═════╩══════════╩════╩════╩════╩════════════╩════════╝
```

You could replace `VALUES` with simple `SELECT` or function call:

```
-- any query
,LATERAL (SELECT t.a+t.b+t.c) AS sub(long_calc)
-- function
,LATERAL random() AS sub(long_calc)
-- function with parameter passing
,LATERAL sin(t.a) AS sub(long_calc)
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8b7e4/5/0)**</kbd>

---

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT id
      ,sub2.long_calc_rand     -- calculated once
      ,random() AS rand        -- calculated every time
FROM tab t
,LATERAL random() AS sub2(long_calc_rand);
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo3`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/79bc6/1/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════╦═════════════════════╦════════════════════╗
║ id  ║   long_calc_rand    ║        rand        ║
╠═════╬═════════════════════╬════════════════════╣
║  1  ║ 0.3426254219375551  ║ 0.8861959744244814 ║
║  2  ║ 0.3426254219375551  ║ 0.8792812027968466 ║
║  3  ║ 0.3426254219375551  ║ 0.8123061805963516 ║
╚═════╩═════════════════════╩════════════════════╝
```

Comment: The calc itself is like 15 lines so it looks ugly :D

Comment: @DaynaJuliana That is why `LATERAL` is nice. You have to place ugly code once :)

Comment: this is great ! is the `VALUES` necessary?

Comment: what is a function call? can i just use a bunch of postgresql functions? right now thats inside a select clause

Comment: @DaynaJuliana Yes, you could use  function and pass arguments from main query too :)

Comment: would this go before or after my joins/ordering? im assuming its after the FROM

Comment: You could place it after last `JOIN`. If you have multiple complex joins "combine" them in one using subquery/CTE

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109302/discussion-between-daynajuliana-and-lad2025).

Comment: @DaynaJuliana Sorry I have to go now. If you need further assistance please consider asking new question. [I believe your original one is solved](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) :)

Comment: Hahaha all good ! I figured it out! Will edit my question to help others