# Declaring a variable in postgres from python

Tags: python, postgresql, variables

I have a variable whose value is set by the user each time the person runs a query.  I am running this script in python which then makes a call to a postgres database.  I am hoping to first assigning a value to the variable in one piece of sql code and then I am hoping to call that variable in a second piece of sql code.

Here is my current code:

First my code to set the postgres variable:

```
sql_stateVar=(""" 
                  tempState VARCHAR:= %s
              """
              ,(stateVar,))
cur.execute(*sql_stateVar)
```

Then with this variable set in postgres, I am going to call this stored variable:

```
sqlquery=("""
    SELECT UPPER(b.state) AS state,
    FROM opentable_full b
    WHERE UPPER(b.state)=UPPER(tempState)
    GROUP BY UPPER(b.state)
""")
```

Then I have the following code:

```
    outputquery = "COPY({0}) TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER".format(sqlquery)

    with open('resultsfile', 'w') as f:
        cur.copy_expert(outputquery, file=f)
```

I have seen several answers regarding the limitations of setting variables in postgres, but as I am new to postgres, I am not sure if these answers are what I need.

For example:
[Is there a way to define a named constant in a PostgreSQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316773/is-there-a-way-to-define-a-named-constant-in-a-postgresql-query?noredirect=1&lq=1)

AND
[How to declare local variables in postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157753/how-to-declare-local-variables-in-postgresql)

Comment: Is it the complete SQLQuerry You are using, coz I think something is missing here ?

Comment: Variables are a [PL/PGSQL language](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html) feature and they only exist inside the function in which they are declared. Why can't you keep the variable in Python and pass it to the query?

Comment: @Take_Care:  Yes, I had removed some portions of the query.  But as a result, the SQLQuery was now incorrect.  I have made some edits to correct this issue

Comment: @Clodoaldo Neto:  That is what I originally tried, but for some reason this did not work.  Hence, I went down the path of declaring the variable in postgres.  If I was to go down that path, can I call on a python-set variable (e.g., stateTemp) inside a sql statement called from within a python script (e.g."""( sqlquery)""" )?

Comment: Use the Psycopg `execute` method to pass parameters to the query. Explain the context for which you want to keep the client state.

Comment: @Clodoaldo Neto:  I have added the rest of the code which calls the sqlquery.  If I was to pass the variable, I am assuming I would replace tempState inside sqlquery code with %s and then pass the variable at the end.  Then I would pass the parameter when calling cur.copy_expert?  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: @Clodoaldo Neto:  Sorry for the delayed response.  I was able to finally get the execute method to pass parameters to the query.  Thanks much for your assistance.