# How do I insert data into table?

Tags: python, database, postgresql

I have created table using this create command as:

> CREATE TABLE test_table(id INT PRIMARY KEY,name
>   VARCHAR(50),price INT)

i want to insert into this table wherein values are stored already in variable

```
bookdb=# name = 'algorithms'
bookdb-# price = 500
bookdb-# INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(1,'name',price);
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "name"
>   LINE 1: name = 'algorithms'

Can anyone point out the mistake and propose solution for the above?

Thanks in advance

**Edit:**

```
import psycopg2
import file_content
try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database='bookdb',user='v22')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS book_details")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE book_details(id INT PRIMARY KEY,name VARCHAR(50),price INT)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO book_details VALUES(1,'name',price)")  
    conn.commit()
except:
    print "unable to connect to db"
```

I have used the above code to insert values into table,variables **name and price** containing the values to be inserted  into table are available in file_content python file and i have imported that file.The normal INSERT statement takes values manually but i want my code to take values which are stored in variables.

Comment: Like the error says: your first line isn't a valid SQL statement. You want to replace the variable content in your python code.

Comment: edited the above code.how to supply values to INSERT statement which stored in variables?

Comment: Hmmm… I thought substantially rewriting a question was frowned upon on StackExchange. This is no longer a Postgres question. This newly rewritten version is a Python programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't have postgres installed here, but you can try this

```
import psycopg2
import file_content
try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database='bookdb',user='v22')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS book_details")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE book_details(id INT PRIMARY KEY,name VARCHAR(50),price INT)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO book_details VALUES(1, '%s', %s)" % (name, price))
    conn.commit()
except:
    print "unable to connect to db"
```

Answer (score 1):

[SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) does not support the concept of variables.

To use variables, you must use a programming language, such as [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java), [C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29), [Xojo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xojo). One such language is [PL/pgSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/pgSQL), which you can think of as a superset of SQL. PL/PgSQL is often [bundled](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html) as a part of Postgres installers, but not always.

I suggest you read some basic tutorials on SQL.

See this similar question: [How do you use script variables in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36959/how-do-you-use-script-variables-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PSQL console:

```
\set name 'algo'
\set price 10
insert into test_table values (1,':name',:price)
\g
```

Comment: thanks it works.But i want it to done in my python code.see my edit