# getting an error ERROR: schema ":schema" does not exist while select nextval of seq

Tags: postgresql, psql

```
select nextval(:schema.seqname) is this correct syntax?
```

I am passing the schema name while executing the script by `-v schema=s1`;

getting an error

> ERROR:  schema ":schema" does not exist

Comment: Whenever I've used nextval, the parameter needed to be in single quotes like this: `SELECT NEXTVAL('schema.seqname')`

Comment: yes.I 'm passing schema name by variable via command line

Comment: I am not using directly schema name in the nextval

Comment: i'm paasing as arg

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT NEXTVAL(:'schema'||'.seqname');
```

This is after a psql line like this:

```
psql -U user -h host -d dbname -v schema="schemaname"
```

Bizarre syntax but Craig Ringer's answer to this question led me to the idea: 
[How do you use script variables in psql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36959/how-do-you-use-script-variables-in-psql)

Comment: getting an error  ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"

Comment: Are you using -c also? Or just connecting with -v and then running the query? Can you give an example of your psql line? I tried this solution with success.

Comment: psql  -d dbname -U username -f create.sql -v schema=post

Comment: So this `SELECT NEXTVAL` is within `create.sql`?

Comment: declare
   v_id bigint;
BEGIN
   if NEW.empid is null then
      select nextval((:'schema'||'.empseq')
      into STRICT v_id
;
      NEW.empid := v_id;
   end if;
RETURN NEW;
End;

Comment: That looks like trigger syntax to me, if you're just trying to say "if I didn't supply an empid on insert than default to the next seq_num", you can supply a default in the table creation code. `CREATE TABLE(empid INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT NEXTVAL('schema.seqname')`. I'm not sure of the syntax to achieve this with the `-f` or `-c` command. Note: I connected with psql and a variable assigned with `-v` and after that ran the `SELECT` in my answer.

Comment: NextVal takes the single quoted variable.As i am passing as variable not possible to achieve this with the syntax

Comment: My only other suggestion would be to try using input redirection rather than the `-f` option. Like this: `psql -d dbname -U user -v schema="post" < create.sql`. I haven't tested this.