# Setting application_name using a variable post connection?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to set the application_name using a variable inside a pl/pgsql function. I need to set a few vars so I'd like to wrap in a single function rather than have the clients run the command several times.

However when I run

```
my_variable := 'foo';
SET application_name = my_variable;
```

It sets the application_name to my_variable instead of foo.

This is on postgresql11. I've tried quoting the variable in various ways to make it evaluate but so far no luck.

When I run a simple

```
SET application_name = 'foo';
```

It works as expected.  I've tried some of the string quoting from another answer: [How do you use script variables in psql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36959/how-do-you-use-script-variables-in-psql) but none of these seemed to work for me.

The code I have so far is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION app_name_test(
                                                p_application_name VARCHAR(64)
                                        ) RETURNS BOOLEAN
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
BEGIN

    RAISE INFO 'Setting Application Name To: %', p_application_name;

    SET application_name = p_application_name;

    RETURN TRUE;
END;
$$;


SELECT app_name_test('This_is_a_test');
```

I'm fairly sure it's possible but I must have to quote the strings in a certain way. Many thanks in advance.

---

**Edit:** The answer in comments from a_horse_with_no_name below solved the issue.

```
EXECUTE FORMAT('SET application_name = %L', p_application_name);
```

Would be interesting though to know why this works for tables (variables expanded) but not for this particular SQL. E.g.

```
SELECT * from table where column = my_var;
```

Works but the above didn't.

Comment: Did you try dynamic SQL? `execute format('set application_name = %L', p_application_name);`

Comment: This worked. Many thanks. I'll edit the question to show solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A statement like

```
SELECT x INTO dest FROM atable WHERE column = my_var;
```

where `my_var` is a PL/pgSQL variable will actually be turned into a parameterized query:

```
SELECT x FROM atable WHERE column = $1;
```

and the value of `my_var` will be supplied as parameter value.

Using variables in PL/pgSQL statements works if and only if the statement supports parameters.

Now `SELECT` supports parameters (as does `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE`), but `SET` (like all “utility statements”) doesn't.

This is why you have to use dynamic SQL if you want to use a variable in a utility statement.