# When aggregating data from multiple inner queries, how to avoid the verbosity and simplify?

Tags: postgresql

Provided you have three tables (user, comment, like)

```
SELECT *
FROM user u
JOIN (SELECT user_id, count(*) as likes
    FROM likes l
    WHERE l.created_on > '2021-10-01' AND l.created_on <= '2021-10-31'
    GROUP BY l.user_id
) as likes ON u.id = likes.user_id
JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, count(*) as comments
    FROM comment c
    WHERE c.created_on > '2021-10-01' AND c.created_on <= '2021-10-31'
) as comments ON u.id = comments.user_id;
```

Is there any way to simplify a query like this? Could the created_on filter dates be declared as variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PL/pgSQL supports variables inside functions, so you could make this a function if you wanted and then query the function results. Say something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_user_interaction_counts
(
   date_start date,
   date_end date
)
RETURNS TABLE(user_id int, like_count int, comment_count int) as $$
SELECT u.id, likes.likes, comments.comments
FROM "user" u
JOIN (SELECT user_id, count(*) as likes
    FROM likes l
    WHERE l.created_on > date_start AND l.created_on <= date_end
    GROUP BY l.user_id
) as likes ON u.id = likes.user_id
JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, count(*) as comments
    FROM comment c
    WHERE c.created_on > date_start AND c.created_on <= date_end
    GROUP BY c.user_id
) as comments ON u.id = comments.user_id

$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

You'd then query it:

```
select * from get_user_interaction_counts('2021-10-01', '2021-10-30')
```

Of course that's probably not what you're after. If you want variables when "just querying", it'll depend on the client you're using. If you're using psql, [it does support variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36959/how-do-you-use-script-variables-in-psql). Other clients may or may not support them, depends.

What you can also do is to rework the query a little bit, like so, with a parameters CTE at the beginning and then use it to join the selected params:

```
WITH parameters AS (
  SELECT '2021-10-01'::date as date_start
       , '2021-10-30'::date as date_end
)
SELECT u.id, likes.likes, comments.comments
FROM "user" u
JOIN (SELECT user_id, count(*) as likes
    FROM likes l
    JOIN parameters par
      ON l.created_on > par.date_start AND l.created_on <= par.date_end
    GROUP BY l.user_id
) as likes ON u.id = likes.user_id
JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, count(*) as comments
    FROM comment c
    JOIN parameters par
      ON c.created_on > par.date_start AND c.created_on <= par.date_end
    GROUP BY c.user_id
) as comments ON u.id = comments.user_id
```

[Here's a dbfiddle demo with both](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=684eeba012f2ed987baf7eed19641a52)

PS. Your queries use inner join so will only include users who both liked and commented. If a user didn't comment, or didn't like anything, they will be excluded because no records will be returned from the joined query.